# ColdFusion - Alternatives to PreCompilation for IPR (Intellectual Property Rights)

Tags: coldfusion, websphere

Our security policy does not allow us to expose our source code to clients.

Typically, in the ColdFusion world a sourceless distribution is carried out by running the code through cfcompile.sh

Unfortunately, code that is precompiled is in my experience not portable across different Operating Systems. I am now looking into alternatives to obfuscate the actual source code.

Do you see any other option besides the precompilation option in the ColdFusion world?

Comment: Any cfcompile variant in my opinion works fine between the same operating system/application server however it does not work across different operating systems/application servers. I do not see a document that discusses what exactly this utility does and any restrictions it has. 

Since my code runs perfectly when I copy the source code from Windows let's say to AIX but when I compile the code (through cfcompile) on Windows and then deploy it to AIX I get many weird errors I am looking for an alternative that works across different OSs.

Answer (score 6):

you might want to check out the cfcompile utility:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=deploying_5.html

two of the features are:

**Precompiling ColdFusion pages:** Precompile your application's CFM pages into Java class files. At runtime, ColdFusion does not have to compile CFM pages.

**Sourceless distribution:** Create CFM pages as Java bytecode. You can deploy these CFM pages instead of CFML source code.

Comment: Actually, we use cfcompile to generate a sourceless deployment, however this has limitations. If I precompiled code on Windows/JRun and I port it to let's say Solaris/WebSphere then it does not run. I get strange errors. This has happened to me when I transfer code across different operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the cfencode executable located in the bin directory to "Encode" the templates in an unreadable manner. This works across all platforms, and has been a feature of ColdFusion for a long time, so it goes back many versions as well.

It should be noted that there are third party utilities to decode the encoded cfm templates to get the source code again. It is a keeping honest people honest solution.