# How to convert coldfusion code to JAVA class files

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

During run time coldfusion converts all the CFM and CFC files in to JAVA class files and processes them. To improve the server response time, i want to deploy the class files directly instead of deploying CFM/CFC files. Any ideas on how to achieve that ?

Comment: So you want to bypass the CFML to Java conversion and run the specific Java classes which convert the CFML or you want to strictly run the converted CFML Java files directly without going through CFML to Java conversion each time before execution. Can you clarify?

Comment: Did you do a search first? A quick search on "ColdFusion deploy class files" returns this as the second result: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/deploying-coldfusion-applications.html  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342785/coldfusion-alternatives-to-precompilation-for-ipr-intellectual-property-right/2343829#2343829  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741197/cfcompile-precompiling-coldfusion-pages-sourceless-distribution .  Voting to close as duplicate.